# Connect Synology NAS to samsung android phone trough sftp with samsungandroid "My Files" app

Tags: samsung, file-system, ftp

There is a "DS File" Synology app to browse your Synology NAS via your Android phone, but the app is really laggy etc. On Samsung phones there is the "My File" app, a file browser that really does the job, and that would be perfect could it browse the NAS. (In fact I already tested it when the phone is on the same (wifi) network as the NAS as the app allows it with the "connect to a network drive (SMB)".)

Now, the app also allows to connect to an FTP or SFTP server. Hence in Synology I did a "control panel -> FTP -> Enable SFTP server" with port number 16666 (in the range allowed by my router) and a "control panel -> Terminal & SNMP -> Enable SSH Service" with the same port. Then I said to my router to forward that port.

In the "My File" app, I did an "add SFTP server" where I added the IP address from the Synology NAS, the 16666 port, my admin user name and password, and I keep having an error not allowing me to connect.

Comment: Is that *"my admin user name and password"* belong to SFTP? Are you sure that Synology SSH server is configured to authenticate using password and not the public/private keys? Are you able to ping Synology server from your phone? Did you scan Synology's port 16666 from phone and it appears open? Did you try to open SFTP from some other host like a PC? Sorry, that's how network troubleshooting proceeds.